# Users page sort order

Tags: bug, status-completed, users

Sorry if this is already been brought up before but I couldn't think of any search terms specific enough to find discussions of it.

I was just taking a peek in the deeper levels of the Users tab, just look to see how many pages back I was and when I got pages in the [region of 1300](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1305) I noticed that for several when more than one user shares the same score their order appears to be selected randomly.

The problem is that in this region there are 5+ pages of people with a 41 reputation and as I clicked forward and backward it wasn't showing me page after page - it shows a page of randomly selected 41 reputation people. I noticed this because three pages deep I saw a username come up again and thought it was strange then I went back to check and THEN when I went forward again the second user wasn't there that time.

I appreciate that the sorting shouldn't be done alphabetically because that just rewards people for having names that start with A but I think the best solution would be to order it by the most recent person to get that score goes at the top of the list.

Comment: `[status-bydesign]`, I'd say.

Comment: It probably was designed this way originally but now there are tens of thousands of users it just makes the long tail of the user page unusable.

Comment: There are several sub-sorts in place now, ultimately by a unique Id